# How can I integrate mixpanel and requirejs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, mixpanel

I'm using RequireJS to load all my javascript as AMD modules. Specifically, I'm using the "shim" configuration to load non-AMD modules.

But I'm getting an 'undefined' object when I tried to load MixPanel.

Here are the relevant files, with my successfully shim'ed Stripe js for comparison.

main.js:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        stripe: 'libs/stripe/stripe',
        mp: 'libs/mixpanel/mixpanel'
    },
    shim: {
        'stripe': {
            exports: 'Stripe'
        },
        'mp': {
            exports: 'MP'
        }
    }
 });
```

`libs/stripe/stripe.js` and `libs/mixpanel/mixpanel.js` both have `(function () {})();` calls as their documentations recommend.

my payment.js (which wraps Stripe):

```
define(['jquery', 'stripe'], function ($, Stripe) {
    var key = "MY_KEY";
    Stripe.setPublishableKey(key);
});
```

my track.js (which wraps MixPanel):

```
define(['jquery', 'mp'], function ($, MP) {
    var token = "MY_TOKEN";
    MP.init(token);
});
```

Comment: worth pointing out: the first argument you're passing into define should be an *array* not an _object_

Comment: that was a mistake in my question. updated.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the mix panel snippet, which I guess you use in `libs/mixpanel/mixpanel.js` is adding a asynchronous `<script>` tag which downloads the full mixpanel library. Since RequireJS prevents the `mixpanel` variable from being attached to the window, it is never updated.

I am still trying to figure out how to make it work and will edit this answer if I figure it out.

*Edit:*

I have found out that mixpanel expects to be able to reassign `window.mixpanel`. So in your case you could do something like:

```
define(['mixpanel'], function (MP) {
    window.mixpanel = MP;
    window.mixpanel.init('TOKEN');
    ...
});
```

And your handlers for mixpanel should then use `window.mixpanel` since that will be the real instance.

Comment: THanks for the answer. So there's no real AMD solution. You always have to use window.mixpanel, yeah?

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729068/mixpanel-2-2-within-an-amd-structured-web-app-e-g-require-js has a better question and answer. Would you agree? Thinking about deleting my Q.

Comment: @EvanHammer that does indeed look like a better answer. If I was still relying on Mixpanel directly that would be the direction I would go (we have changed to Segment.io for handling our tracking and analytics).

Comment: how do you like Segment.io?

Comment: It works very well for us. We have a REST server, and our JS UI application, and using segment.io has allowed us to keep most of our tracking in the server. Only thing we have run into is ensuring the right data is sent to the right integration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with shim, but it seems that you should have

```
'mp': {
    exports: 'mixpanel'
}
```

since the Mixpanel library exposes that, not `window.MP`.

Comment: I tried that as well, but it didn't work. MixPanel does something very strange around namespacing.

Comment: When i tried the shim config you suggested, my `track.js` script had `MP === mixpanel` even though `mixpanel` should have been removed from the global namespace. In addition, not all `MP.track()` or `mixpanel.track()` commands actually worked.