# Mixpanel 2.2 within an AMD structured web-app - e.g. require.js

Tags: requirejs, amd, mixpanel

I'm attempting to make use of Mixpanel event tracking in a single page site based on Backbone.js and require.js.

Looking at the [snippet](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/tracking-an-event#install-the-library) that Mixpanel provide for cut-and-pasting into a regular webpage, I can tell they've rolled their own async loading mechanism that pulls in the actual [Mixpanel API](http://api.mixpanel.com/site_media/js/api/mixpanel-2.2.js) from a standalone resource, do some extra work to setup 'people' and other attributes, and finally expose the 'mixpanel' object through the global namespace.

I've tried to add shim config entries for either the snippet or the standalone API but neither work well.

Through my research, I found a [project on github](https://github.com/dzello/mixpanel-amd) that does exactly what I want, however it's a few years old and is based on the 'old' mixpanel API. In the new version, Mixpanel have made some non-trivial changes to the snippet and API that I just can't get my head around.

I'm hoping somebody understands the Mixpanel snippet and/or AMD and require.js and can step me through this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two funny things that makes this an odd problem to solve:

1. The mixpanel lib requires you to have window.mixpanel defined before you load it.
2. The mixpanel lib re-defines window.mixpanel as a part of its init process.

Out of the box, the mixpanel snippet doesn't support get_distinct_id (and any call that is, by definition, synchronous) until the lib is loaded but does stub out other methods (such as track) BEFORE loading the mixpanel lib for the sake of queueing. Therefore we have two options:

**Option 1. Drop async support and wait until the lib is loaded - [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jbwyme/6677532)**

This method works by creating a pre-init module to setup the window.mixpanel deps needed by the mixpanel lib and then specifying that as a dependency to the lib itself. Then requiring "mixpanel" will block until the lib is fully loaded.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mixpanel AMD Example - Sync</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.8/minified/require.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            requirejs.config({
                paths : { 'mixpanel': "//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min" },
                shim: {
                    'mixpanel': {
                        deps: ['mixpanel-preinit'],
                        exports: 'mixpanel'
                    }
                }
            });
            define("mixpanel-preinit", function(require) {
                // this is a stripped down version of the mixpanel snippet that removes the loading of the lib via external script tag and the stubs for queuing calls
                var b=window.mixpanel=window.mixpanel||[];var i,g;b._i=[];b.init=function(a,e,d){function f(b,h){var a=h.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],h=a[1]);b[h]=function(){b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}"undefined"!==typeof d?c=b[d]=[]:d="mixpanel";b._i.push([a,e,d])};b.__SV=1.2;
                b.init("YOUR TOKEN");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require(['mixpanel'], function(mixpanel) {
                mixpanel.track("my event", {prop1: "val1"}); 
                console.log(mixpanel.get_distinct_id()); 
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Option 2. Provide a "loaded" callback to update the module's properties. - [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jbwyme/6677566)**

If you REALLY want async support, you'll need to update your stub's methods once the mixpanel lib is loaded. I don't recommend this because (among other reasons) it results in window.mixpanel !== mixpanel after the copy. This also means you must protect against race conditions on synchronous calls like get_distinct_id(). If the lib hasn't loaded yet, it'll be undefined. NOTE: I recommend that if you must have async support, you should just call through window.mixpanel instead of all of this craziness.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mixpanel AMD Example - Async</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.8/minified/require.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            requirejs.config({
                paths : { 'mixpanel-lib': "//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min" }
            });

            define("mixpanel", function(require) {
                var b = window.mixpanel || [];
                if (!b.__SV) { var i, g; window.mixpanel = b; b._i = []; b.init = function (a, e, d) { function f(b, h) { var a = h.split("."); 2 == a.length && (b = b[a[0]], h = a[1]); b[h] = function () { b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0))) } } var c = b; "undefined" !== typeof d ? c = b[d] = [] : d = "mixpanel"; c.people = c.people || []; c.toString = function (b) { var a = "mixpanel"; "mixpanel" !== d && (a += "." + d); b || (a += " (stub)"); return a }; c.people.toString = function () { return c.toString(1) + ".people (stub)" }; i = "disable track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" "); for (g = 0; g < i.length; g++) f(c, i[g]); b._i.push([a, e, d]) }; b.__SV = 1.2 }

                // go ahead and start loading the mixpanel-lib
                require(['mixpanel-lib']);

                b.init("YOUR TOKEN", {loaded: function() { 
                    // now that we know mixpanel is loaded, copy the prop references to our module def
                    for(var prop in window.mixpanel) {
                        b[prop] = window.mixpanel[prop];
                    }
                }}); 
                return b;
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require(['mixpanel'], function(mixpanel) {
                mixpanel.track("my event", {prop1: "val1"}); 
                console.log(mixpanel.get_distinct_id()); // probably undefined
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We used a very similar approach to the 2nd method, with the addition of a promise that resolves when mixpanel calls our 'loaded' callback. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Option 1. worked fine for me until I ran my code through the RequireJS optimizer. The optimized output has the Mixpanel lib code with a shim module definition appended after it: define("mixpanel", ["mixpanelPreInit"], (function (global) { .... }(this)));

Unfortunately, the Mixpanel lib code is still evaluated even before the module definition is. When it is evaluated, it expects the initialization code to already have run.

Answer (score 5):

Following solution works for mixpanel api 2.2

add mixpanel with following shim -

```
path : {
    'mixpanel' : '//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min'
}

shim : {
    'mixpanel' : {
        exports : 'mixpanel'
    },
}
```

and use following requirejs module instead of the the snippet given by mixpanel -

```
define('mixpanel-snippet', [], function(){
    var b = window.mixpanel || [];
    if (!b.__SV) {
        var i, g;
        window.mixpanel = b;
        b._i = [];
        b.init = function (a, e, d) {
            function f(b, h) {
                var a = h.split(".");
                2 == a.length && (b = b[a[0]], h = a[1]);
                b[h] = function () {
                    b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)))
                }
            }
            var c = b;
            "undefined" !==
            typeof d ? c = b[d] = [] : d = "mixpanel";
            c.people = c.people || [];
            c.toString = function (b) {
                var a = "mixpanel";
                "mixpanel" !== d && (a += "." + d);
                b || (a += " (stub)");
                return a
            };
            c.people.toString = function () {
                return c.toString(1) + ".people (stub)"
            };
            i = "disable track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" ");
            for (g = 0; g < i.length; g++)
                f(c, i[g]);
            b._i.push([a, e, d])
        };
        b.__SV = 1.2
    }
    b.init("YOUR TOKEN");
    require(['mixpanel'], function(mixpanel){});

    return b;
});
```

I simply took the snippet from mixpanel, removed the async mixpanel load and wrapped it in a requirejs module definition.

Change "YOUR TOKEN" at the bottom of the module.

Example use with a require call --

```
require([
    'mixpanel-snippet',
], function (mixpanel) {
        mixpanel.track("Landing Page with AMD SHIM");
});
```

EDIT: The second one is the right answer after a little modification. the way mixpanel script works is it needs the init call in the snippet to happen before the actual mixpanel load. the trick is to require mixpanel after the init call.i have edited the 2nd answer and removed the first one and [here's the gist](https://gist.github.com/mohitmayank/6162576)

EDIT: Answer to comment from @johanandren 
Requirejs follows AMD principle and the order in which scripts will load is not fixed. In case you need to load mixpanel before using mixpanel-snippet, following hack can be used.

```
//at the end of mixpanel-snippet code mentioned above force the script to block until mixpanel is loaded

b.init("YOUR TOKEN");
var wait = true;
require(['mixpanel'], function(mixpanel){wait = false;});
while(wait){}
return b;
```

** it violates the Async load features of AMD, forces the script to block plus even in vanila mixpanel snippet the load is async and availability for initial api calls is not guaranteed

Comment: I've tried both ways and I receive a js errors.The #2 suggestion yields 
`'Mixpanel error: 'mixpanel' object not initialized. Ensure you are using the latest version of the Mixpanel JS Library along with the snippet we provide.` `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__SV' of undefined"`

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/dwightgunning/6088c0b0056838c0eb47) with my attempt at using the 2nd alternative.

Comment: Apologies for late reply. i was on a vacation. i have solved the issue and updated the answer. The mixpanel API assumes that the sync load will not happen before the call to the init method. and hence the problem . the previous snippet loaded mixpanel before the snippet. This can be corrected with a simple require call post the snippet init. I have also created a new public [Gist](https://gist.github.com/mohitmayank/6162576)

Comment: Tried this solution but it does not work for us, the scripts depending on mixpanel-snippet will run before mixpanel has been completely loaded or initialized, so it will seem to have some methods .track for example that will do nothing, and will not at all have other methods, like get_distinct_id

Comment: in such a case you need to bootstrap mixpanel-snippet at the very start, in your first require() call and force mixpanel to load before moving forward. I have edited the answer and included the force **hack** in comment block. alternatively you can use load plugin. more info [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html#apiload) and [here](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/Loader-Plugins).

Comment: This solution almost works for me but ultimately fails. The events I try to `track` never come through, but if I `console.log(mixpanel)` (the locally-loaded AMD module, not the `window.mixpanel` global), I see a bunch of extra arrays added to the object which store the events I'm trying to track. Presumably this is because this local instance mixpanel is never initialised? I'm stumped.

Comment: I was able to make track calls successfully with blocking load. I guess the problem is with a load sequence. Josh Wymer's solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  Place your mixpanel snippet in your js/lib directory named mixpanel-snippet.js.

In your app.js add the following shim to require.config:

```
'mixpanel-snippet': {
  exports: 'mixpanel'
}
```

In your require function add 'mixpanel-snippet' to the required array and initialize mixpanel:

```
require(['jquery', 'backbone', 'app/router', 'mixpanel'], function ($, Backbone, Router) {
    var router = new Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
    mixpanel.init(key);
    mixpanel.track("Landed on Start up Page");
});
```

I can provide a full app.js example if it would help but this should get your started.  Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thx will check it out shortly.

Comment: I could be misreading this, but doesn't this just use the global `window.mixpanel` object so you're not really gaining anything from the AMD loading?

Answer (score 0):

As of mixpanel's 2.7.x release, they now support multiple AMD/UMD versions compatible with requirejs, you can grab it on their github page: https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-js

```
requirejs(['./mixpanel.amd'], function(mixpanel) {

    mixpanel.init("FAKE_TOKEN", {
        debug: true,
        loaded: function() {
            mixpanel.track('loaded() callback works but is unnecessary');
            alert("Mixpanel loaded successfully via RequireJS/AMD");
        }
    });

    mixpanel.track('Tracking after mixpanel.init');

});
```